# Visual studio check out all designer files (Xamarin IOS)

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, tfs, xamarin.ios, storyboard

How can we work as a team on a Xamarin IOS project controlled by TFS?

When I open a storyboard, Visual Studio automatically checks out all the designer files of the project, not only the files assigned to the current storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go to **Tools > Options > Source Control > Environment** and indeed all are checked off and has both " *save*" & " *edit*" set to "Check out automatically."

Just setting has both " *save*" & " *edit*" set to "**Prompt for checkout**."

[image]

Now the behavior is  including prompting for a checkout when opening a designer file. You can't open a storyboard and only the file assigned to current storyboard auto checked out. You need to manually check them out. Or you could use a [local workspace](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace#why-should-i-use-a-local-workspace) which work offline easily.